# Use the Mean Value Theorem to show that the only answers for $5^x -3^x =4^x -2^x$ are $1$ and $0$

Tags: real-analysis

That question is equivalent to proving that $f(x)=5^x+2^x-3^x-4^x$ have only two roots, $0$ and $1$. But that’s everything I’ve made so far.

Comment: Hint, look at the function $f(y) = (y+2)^x - y^x$ (treating $x$ as constant) and apply MVT on the interval $2 \leq y \leq 3$.

Comment: It worked, thank you so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following the hint by Tob Ernack let $f(y)=(y+2)^x-y^x$ then by MVT

$$\frac{f(3)-f(2)}{3-2}=f’(c)=0 \quad,\;\quad c\in(2,3)$$

$$f’(c)=x(c+2)^{x-1}-xc^{x-1}=x\big((c+2)^{x-1}-c^{x-1}\big)=0$$

that is

- $x=0$
- $(c+2)^{x-1}=c^{x-1}\Rightarrow (x-1)\log (c+2)=(x-1)\log c\\\Rightarrow x-1=0$